# Are all single letters in English considered words?

Tags: meaning

For example, would you consider 'e' to be a full-fledged word? I'll delete my post if this relies too much on opinion.

(We may ignore obvious single-letter words such as 'a' , 'I' here.)

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Why ignore conventional words? (What's an *un*conventional word anyway?)

Comment: @Araucaria Man 'Is "a" a word?' isn't a fit for ELL, never mind ELU.

Comment: Is there a context for this? Are you considering a word count, etc?

Comment: @JimMack It's just from an argument between two friends.

Comment: Maybe the answer can be found by asking in what circumstance 'e' can be a word.

Comment: @RoaringFish 'E' was just an example. I'm asking about letters in general.

Comment: Hmmm... that puts a different light on this. Maybe worth answering after all!

Comment: There is no single, universally-applicable definition for the word "word".

Comment: Individual letters can be words if you want to understand this exchange: "abcd goldfish?" "lmno goldfish." "osar.  cmp?" (some additional punctuation is required.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most dictionaries consider individual letters to be words, specifically nouns that are defined as the letter themselves.

For instance, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e) defines 'e' as:

> a :  the 5th letter of the English alphabet
>
> b :  a graphic representation of this letter
>
> c :  a speech counterpart of orthographic e

M-W provides some example sentences:

> - *a word that begins with an e*
> - *a word that begins with e*
> - *a song in the key of E*

[Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/e) also defines 'e' as the fifth letter of the alphabet.  In this sense, the individual letters are nouns and would be considered words.

'E' is not the only case, you can search dictionaries for other individual letters and find similar results.

Comment: "the 5th letter of the English alphabet" is a description, not a definition.

Comment: @RoaringFish well, it's how the dictionary defines it as a noun.  Consider M-W's definition of "three." *a number that is one more than 2*.  Sure, it sounds silly, but that's the definition.  But notably, "3" is not in the dictionary, because unlike "three" or "e", "3" is not a word, but a numeral.

Comment: You are arguing in circles. You are saying 'e' must be a word because you insist that the description is a definition, but it can only be a definition if 'e' is a word. A circular argument. By definition.

Comment: @RoaringFish That's not what I'm saying. If anything, you could accuse me of *argumentum ad auctoritatem* because I'm saying "it's a word because a dictionary defined it as a noun."  Dictionaries do define things that are arguably not words, like "i.e.", but then it labels them "abbreviation."  What I'm ultimately saying is "**a dictionary defined it as a noun, which is a type of word, and I'm deferring to the dictionary's authority on words**."

Comment: If it is defined as a noun, then what is the referent? It is a noun only so far as 'the second letter is an 'e' - it takes an article,so it must be a noun. By that argument we can also say 'the second digit is a 3', making 3 a noun and by your reasoning a word.

Comment: @RoaringFish You seem to be arguing that it’s not a word because what the dictionary gives is a description, not a definition; and it cannot have a definition because it’s not a word. That’s no less circular. (The real trouble with this question is, of course, that it’s essentially unanswerable because there is no definition of what a _word_ is to begin with.)

Comment: It is more that what the dictionary gives is a description, not a meaning, and if it has no meaning it is not a word.

Answer (score 2):

I think the crux of an answer to the question is deciding what a word is, which is not so straight forward. Is *Google* the noun the same word as *google* the verb, or are they two separate words? What about adjectives or adverbs? Or marking for person, number, or time? More broadly, you could probably argue that it is a word if it has attached meaning, but then what does *the* mean? Okay... maybe we can say even more broadly that it is a word if it has an attached meaning or function.

So.. run with that and we could say that a letter is a word if it has a meaning or function, but then we run into the next problem - is a word a sound or orthographic? Plenty of people use /e/ to indicate surprise, but it is usually written as "eh", or /t/ to 'tut'. Do they count as a 'single letter' being a word or not? Only a single 'letter' is uttered, but they are written as multiple letters.

Perhaps the answer is that some single sounds that correspond to a single letter can be considered to have a function and therefore be a word, but not single written letters - with the exceptions you mentioned.

Answer (score -5):

I feel like this is opinion based. But I think vowels and nasal consonants could be considered single words when used in a specific way.

When expressing a sound in writing, "e" could be a single word. In some accent, the sound "e" is used instead of "huh", although it is rarely written as so. If you wanted to capture the true sound of a person's question you could write, "e?" Although without the intonation it probably will not be as effective as "huh?". Additionally, "m" and "n" could also indicate a person is thinking, actively listening to another, or subtly disagreeing.

Example:

C1 "I think cats are the best animals!!"

C2 "N..., well, that is an opinion. I personally like dogs"

C1 "M... we can agree to disagree, e?

C2 "I guess, U and I can still b friends.

Comment: In which dialects is "e" considered the equivalent of "huh"? And is that "e" as in eagle, or "e" as in extra?

Comment: Ops, I am editing now. I meant accents, not dialects. Thank you for catching that. It would be found in Wisconsin accents.